# How to assign more than one parameter for one a4j:jsFunction?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Is there a way to declare more than one "assignTo" attribute to one a4j:jsFunction? Or can i set more than one value to one "assignTo" attribute of one a4j:jsFunction?

This for example:

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="newJsFunc" ajaxSingle="true" id="arrJsFunc">
   <a4j:actionparam name="param1" assignTo="#{bean.value}" assignTo="#{bean.value}"
            actionListener="#{bean.actionListenerMethod}" />
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `a4j:param` inside `a4j:jsFunction` instead of `a4j:actionparam`. In `assignTo` you can assign value for only 1 bean property. See description of `assignTo` attribute in [VDL doc](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_3_X/vdldoc/):

> EL expression for updatable bean property. This property will be updated if the parent command component performs an actionEvent.

You can include as many `<a4j:param>` tags as you need. See book Practical RichFaces Chapter 3 (Listing 3-20). Pseudocode:

```
<a4j:jsFunction>
    <a4j:param name="param1" assignTo="#{someBean.value1}" />
    <a4j:param name="param2" assignTo="#{someBean.value2}" />
    <a4j:param name="param3" assignTo="#{someBean.value3}" />
</a4j:jsFunction>
```